# How to fetch tweets since last three months by a user using twitter API

Tags: twitter

You can use `since_id` & `max_id` to fetch tweets between a specific ID.

I want to know how to fetch tweets posted within the last three months, but I don't know how to find the tweet ID, which was posted before three months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The twitter api has the search call method. You're already using `since_id` for the ids, but it looks like you want to use dates as well.

The two date methods (year-month-day) are:

- `hashtag since:1988-06-28` - Searches for "hashtag" and sent since date "1988-06-28".
- `hashtag until:2013-07-12` - Searches for "hashtag" and sent before date "2013-07-12".

Those two date examples (apart from the actual dates) are plucked straight from the documentation. If you want the last three months, just:

- Calculate three months past to the following format: YYYY-MM-DD.
- Use that in the since query

As of today, three months past is: 2013-04-12

`since: 2013-04-12` - would be what you require in your `GET` request. [Documentation Link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

Comment: since, until is available for search query. But i need this in https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json

Comment: Why don't you try a search query and specify the user using `:from` - that's the equivalent of the specific user's tweets, and allows you to use search?

Comment: ya, but the output we get is quite different from search query. I need many information like: Number of times mentioned on Twitter, Number following on Twitter, Number of favourited tweets on Twitter etc...
To do that, I prefer user/timeline query.

Comment: Short of looping your data in your own code and manually calculating the dates, you have no other options - the twitter API doesn't allow you to use the date parameters in `user/timeline` - that's their chosen limitation, unfortunately.

Comment: since and until does not get me the expected result as i am trying it https://apigee.com/console/twitter .. as well as my app ( using Meteor/Node.JS Package ) ...

Comment: The limit for since and until is one week:

Comment: By default Search API returns 7 days data only. How can I retrieve last 30 days tweets.

Comment: has anyone found a solution for this yet?

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather have you gone onto the twitter docs and looked directly there? They're not as bad as they used to be from what I remember.

Comment: @Jimbo yeah I've been searching through them for a while, haven't been able to find anything :/